# Browser's not displaying images correctly

Tags: image, google-chrome, browser, opera

Long story short, all images in browser are displayed wierd.

Here is the comparison between browser and window's image viewer on the same image (downloaded) :https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkiNl.jpg

This problem started on chrome, so I installed opera because the problem was persistent and found no answer to my question. Now after a while the problem started to appear on opera too. I'm baffled why this suddenly happened and why is persistent even after windows restart...

I have no idea why this would happen, so maybe you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome on my machine started doing this around the same time. After some digging around and trial and error I think it's having issues with some monitor colour profiles.

I did manage to get a workaround in the end by changing the colour profile of the monitor to sRGB IEC61966-2.1. In Windows 8.1:

Control Panel > Color Management then select your monitor.
Make sure *Use my settings for this device* is checked. 
Add the sRGB IEC61966-2.1 profile and set it to default

Restart Chrome and you should be able to see the proper amount of colours again.